# How to convert an iterative non-dynamic method with nested for-loop to a recursive dynamic method in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I have a class SED_PP that has an ArrayList called children which contains other SED_PP. I am trying to get write a method which can tell the user if one SED_PP object can be a child of another SED_PP object.

I have one iterative and non-dynamic method isChild(SED_PP sed) which does not go through all the arraylists in the object ad its children has.

```
public class SED_PP 
{
    private ArrayList<SED_PP> children = new ArrayList<SED_PP>();

    public ArrayList<SED_PP> getChildren() { return children;}
    //other methods

    public boolean IsChild(SED_PP sed)
    {
        boolean answer = false;
        if (this.children.contains(sed))
            answer = false;
        else{
            for (SED_PP s : this.children){
                if(!s.getChildren().isEmpty())
                    answer = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return answer;
    }
}
```

The isChild method shown does not go through all of the arraylist that parent SED_PP object has. For example, if parent A has child B, B has a child C and C has a child D, the current isChild method will not return true for A.IsChild(D) when it should be.

I think I need to use recursion for this problem but I am not very good at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need recursion to solve your problem. Your code just need a fix in this part

```
for (SED_PP s : this.children) {

     if(!s.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
        answer = true;
     }
}
```

You didn't check if B has a child C and C has a child D, you only ask whether B has children or not. You should change `IsChild` method code this way.

```
public boolean IsChild(SED_PP sed)
{       
    if (this.children.contains(sed)) {
        return true;
    } 

    for (SED_PP s : this.children) {

        if (s.IsChild(sed)) {
            return true;
        }            
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I used your code but it was returning false when it was supposed return true. So I change the true to false and vice verse and now it’s working! Thank you for your help

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I fixed the issue in the answer